# trigger jquery event after clicking <a> 3 times

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I’m trying to setup an notice that only gets triggered if the user clicks the `<a>` tag 3 times.

To generate the notice I'm using a jQuery lightbox, called fancybox.

So far I've got the fancybox all setup but I'm not sure how to only trigger it after 3 clicks on the a tag.

Any ideas how I would do this?

The js I'm using to call the lightbox is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
```

I've setup a [jsFiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/pudle/XWHga/1/) it.

Comment: iT IS triggering on frist click.. :O

Comment: yep, thats the bit im having trouble with i want it to trigger on the 3rd click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep track of the number of times the element was clicked :

```
var clicked = 0;

$('.fancybox').on('click', function (e) {
    clicked++;

    if (clicked >= 3) {
        clicked = 0;
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XWHga/5/)

Comment: This only works the first time. After, fancybox will always fire on first click. I added an answer where I tweaked your code.

Answer (score 3):

@adeneo's answer is correct IF you want that functionality the **first time only**. With that code, if you close fancybox and then click the link ONCE again, fancybox will fire on first click now on.

IF what you want is fancybox ALWAYS firing after 3 clicks at any time, then tweak @adeneo's code this way :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = 0;
    $('.fancybox').on('click', function (e) {
        clicked++;
        if (clicked >= 3) {
            clicked = 0;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }).fancybox();
});
```

See **[forked JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YJYh8/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.data()` to keep track:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.fancybox').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            count = ($this.data('click-count') || 0) + 1;
         if (count === 3) {
             $('.fancybox').fancybox();
         }
         $this.data('click-count', count);
     });         
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XWHga/3/

The advantage of using `.data()` is that the counts are tied to the links themselves, so if you happen to have multiple links to keep track of there's no messiness trying to keep track of which external counters belong with which links.

Comment: This only works the first time. After that, fancybox will always fire on first click.

Comment: That's an easy enough tweak (just use `%`) - wasn't clear from the question that it was to be *every* third click.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a click listener and keep a variable which updates when clicked.

something like this:

```
var clickCounter = 0;
object.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter == 3) {
        //Open it
    }
});
```